# How to modify formatted string with 'positional' option by using swift's DateComponentsFormatter

Tags: swift, date, nstimeinterval, dateformatter, nsdatecomponentsformatter

I want to get a relatively formatted string from TimeInterval. So I have tried following code to get custom formatted string:

```
let ft = DateComponentsFormatter()
ft.unitsStyle = .positional
ft.zeroFormattingBehavior = .dropAll
// TimeInterval can be either 5400 or 3600 or 1800 as well
let formattedString = ft.string(from: TimeInterval(1800))
```

But I can't format my string like this: "1:30h" and if i have only hour "1h" or i have only minutes "30m"

Comment: 1800 seconds is 30 minutes. Of course you are not going to get one and a half hour out of that...

Comment: @Sweeper - sorry it's hardcoded value for testing. Actually it can be for example 5400 or 3600 as well

Comment: It seems like the `.abbreviated` unit style is the closest to what you want. If you want to get exactly "1:30h" (which IMO is a terrible format), then you should write your own formatter. `DateComponentsFormatter` isn't about specifying your exact time interval format. It's about describing your format in a much high-level of abstraction (What style of units? How should 0s be formatted? What units are allowed? Is there a time remaining phrase? etc).

Comment: @Sweeper, thanks for the reply. So to write my own formatter i should completely replace DateCompontnetsFormatter?